# Do I have to use the CAN protocol that the motor controller uses in order to communicate with it?

Tags: control, motor, can

I have a question about using the CAN bus to control motor controllers. Do I have to use the CAN protocol that the motor controller uses, e.g. CANopen CiA DS 301 CiA profile 402, in order to communicate with it? Or I can just use any CAN API library, let’s say SocketCan, to communicate with the motor controller?

Comment: why would you want to create tags? ... why don't you use existing tags that are appropriate  ... `can` and `control` and `library` would be good ... `motor` and `motion` not so much ... your question is not really about a motor

Comment: Its about motor controllers... but since there is not a tag called motor-controller I put motor instead...

Comment: that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CANopen is a application level protocol and socketcan is at the transport level.

You can send Canopen messages using socketcan without any problems.

You can compose canopen messages by hand but it will be a lot easier if you use a library